# Is there a way to Remove/Update a line at somewhere in the middle of a large text file in Python?

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to do this without loading the entire file into memory or creating an alternate text file. The text file is very large. So it doesn't make sense to load the entire file into memory. Creating a new file(even for temporary purposes) is also not preferred. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: So how do you decide which line to update?

Comment: Not exactly in the middle, but any line somewhere in the middle.

Comment: So then how do you decide which line to update? A line that starts with `the`? A line that has 20 words? You have to be specific on that

Comment: I want to remove every line that has 'hello' in it (for example)

Answer (score 0):

Simple do

```
with open("sample.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'hello' in line:
            modify_func(line)
```

This actually won't load your entire file into memory but only a line at a time, which is then treated as garbage data and erase after an iteration, so it will efficiently modify your file.

Comment: The real problem is in the modify_func(). How do I define it? What is the logic behind that function? As far as I know, iterating though the file line by line only gets a copy of what's in the current line and it is not possible to edit that line in the file directly within this scope.

Comment: If I can get the lines in the above mentioned way, append them to a string and write it to a new file(or the source file itself), then the string will contain the entire data (which is very huge) in the memory.

Comment: My problem is not in the reading part sir, It is in the writing part.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a particular position in the file that you want to write to then you can seek it to that point and then read/ write at that point.

Removing a line requires you to open it properly and rewrite it to source excluding that line

example for seek

```
lineno=301
linelen=14
with open('foo.txt','w+') as file:
    file.seek(lineno * (linelen+2))
    line=file.readline()
    file.seek(1,-linelen-2)
    file.write('hello\n')
```

Comment: Linelen +2 is for escaping `\n` charater in each line